# Finding solutions to $f(x)=p''(x)+xp(x)$

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to find all $f(x)\in \mathcal{P}_4(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f(x)=p''(x)+xp(x)$ has a solution.

Note that $\mathcal{P}_n(\mathbb{R})$ denotes the vector space of all polynomials of degree at most $n$ over $\mathbb{R}$.

My idea is to define the linear map $T: \mathcal{P}_3(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow \mathcal{P}_4(\mathbb{R})$ by $T(p(x))=p''(x)+xp(x)$ and then determine the range of $T$. I see that the zero polynomial is one such $f(x)$ and that any other such $f(x)$ will have degree $k+1$, where $k$ is the degree of the solution $p(x)$.

I also realize that $T$ cannot be surjective as $\dim \mathcal{P}_3(\mathbb{R})< \dim \mathcal{P}_4(\mathbb{R})$. This, I think, has given me trouble.

I also would like to know if $T$ is injective.

I am not familiar with using matrices explicitly to solve differential equations, so I'd appreciate seeing how to determine the range just with the machinery of linear maps.

Comment: Your idea is sound. What is your question, exactly?

Comment: Is $p \in P_n(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: @IgorRivin I am unable to actually find the range.

Comment: You know the dimension of the range. Now, pick your favorite basis  of polynomial of degree at most $3$ ($1, x, x^2, x^3$ is  my favorite) and see where they go. Their images will span the range.

Comment: @IgorRivin I know the dimension of the codomain. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @IgorRivin Actually, is the kernel trivial? In that case, I would know the dimension of the range (and that T is injective) and that the image of the basis you chose is a basis for the range.

Comment: Can the degree of the second derivative of a polynomial be greater than the degree of the polynomial?

Comment: @IgorRivin No, but if $p(x)$ is not the zero polynomial, then $tp(x)$ is not the zero polynomial, hence $p''(x)+tp(x)$ is not the zero polynomial, right?

Comment: If by $t$ you mean $x$ then yes.